# What is wrong with my strawberry plants? Nutrient deficiencies? Should I let them flower?

Tags: leaves, nutrients, strawberries

On some plants, the ends of new leaves are brown and dry and keep the new leaves from unfolding. On older leaves, there are purple areas, and some edges are dry.

A few weeks ago, I started supplementing the 
once a day drip water (ph balanced to 6) with nutrient water,
with approx 20 ml (4 teaspoons) per plant, a day, general hydroponics grow, micro, bloom 3:2:1
because some new leaves were more yellow in the flesh than green in the veins, and there were some purple areas. And I found http://landresources.montana.edu/soilfertility/nutrientdeficiencies.html

The new leaves having brown dry tips is new since I started the nutrient.

I have been cutting off older leaves as they get really dry or brown.

I have been cutting off the runners and flowers as they start, in an attempt to establish the roots and leaves better first. But now I'm worried I might be missing out on my opportunity to grow berries.

I got these seascape everbearing strawberry as bare root plants via the mail around Nov 15 2018
They grow inside in sterile soil enriched with worm casings, mixed 2 parts soil and 1 part sand.

1
[image]

2
[image]

3
[image]

4
[image]

5
[image]

6
[image]